# Finding a bijective morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am given two Varieties $Z=V(x^2+y^2+1) \subset C^2$ and $W=V(x^2-y^2-1) \subset C^2$. We need to find a bijective morphism f such is an isomorphism with the inverse of f.

First how we defined isomorphism was by if $f: V \rightarrow W$ is a morphism and $g:W \rightarrow V$ is a morphism such that $f \circ g =id_w$ and $g \circ f = id_v$

My attempt was that I was relying that I can talk about the coordinate rings and maybe from there I can get the proper morphism I considered the following The coordinate ring $K[Z]= k[x,y,z]/I(Z)$ and the coordinate ring $K[W]=k[x,y,z]/I(W)$ . Then I was thinking that I can define a K-algebra homomorphism between the two.
Say $f^*(a)=a$ for all constants and $f^*(x)=x$ , $f(y)=-y$  that way we can take the zero in the coordinate ring $K[Z]$ to the zero in the other coordinate ring.
$f^*(x^2+y^2-1)=x^2-y^2-1$ 
Then I was thinking that the inverse would be the exact same thing. This shows that $f^* $ is a k-algebra isomorphism. Then I was thinking I can somehow lift this $f^*$ to the varieties. Please comment and tell me if this is how I should be doing this and if I am on track. Thank you guys =)

Comment: The correct $K$-algebra homomorphism would be $x \mapsto ix, y \mapsto y$.

Comment: Can you please walk me how you saw that

Comment: The only difference of the ideals is the sign of $x^2$. You of course change that sign by replacing $x$ with $ix$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $K[x,y] \to K[x,y]/(x^2-y^2-1), x \mapsto ix, y \mapsto y$ maps $x^2+y^2+1$ to zero, hence induces a map $$K[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1) \to K[x,y]/(x^2-y^2-1)$$
which by contravariance induces a map $$V(x^2-y^2-1) \to V(x^2+y^2+1), (x,y) \mapsto (ix,y)$$
This is easily checked to be an isomorphism, since the inverse is given by $(x,y) \mapsto (-ix,y)$.

Comment: I agree that is what I got as well after I read the helpful comment above.Thank you =)